# How to return an unique checked = false item from the DB?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array/list which all the items are set to `checked=true` by default, but I have an special case, I want to set to `checked=false` the `id:25` by default, got it ? all the items set to `checked=true` except the `id:25`.

So how can I do that from the Nodejs part ?

here I have the code which is activated every time you uncheck any of the items

```
module.exports = {

  sportChecked: function(params) {
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
      SportSelection.findOne({
        user: params.user
      }).exec(function(err, sportChecked) {
        var newSport;
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error('Error finding user'));
          console.error(err);
        }else if (sportChecked) {
          newSport = sportChecked.sport || [];
          if (_.includes(sportChecked.sport, params.sport)) {
            sportChecked.sport = _.pull(newSport, params.sport);
            sportChecked.sport = _.difference(newSport, params.sport);
          }else {
            newSport.push(params.sport);
            sportChecked.sport = newSport;
          }
          SportSelection.update({
            user: params.user
          },
          {
            sport: newSport
          }).exec(function(err, sportCheckedUpdated) {
            if (err) {
              reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
            }else {
              fullfill(sportCheckedUpdated);
            }
          });
          if (sportChecked.sport) {
            sportChecked.sport.push(params.sport);
          }else {
            sportChecked.sport = [params.sport];
          }
        }else {
          SportSelection.create({
            sport: [params.sport],
            user: params.user
          }).exec(function(err, created) {
              if (err) {
                reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
              }else {
                fullfill(created);
              }
            });
        }
      });
    });
  },
...
};
```

the `sportChecked` param returns the `id`s of the sports checked to false. So what I need is to include `id:10` in that param.

so what are your suggestions here ?

Comment: if you are using mongoose using bluebird is an overkill since exec() returns a promise

Comment: are you including the id inside the params? like params.id?

Comment: @jack.the.ripper umm nope, I am not including it that way, do you think is better to do it from here ? or from the FrontEnd?

Comment: @jack.the.ripper see this ```if (_.includes(sportChecked.sport, params.sport))```, there is the part where I need to exclude the id I mentioned